# generate lincense report using maven

Tags: maven, licensing

I'm trying to generate a license file using a plugin of maven, but it does not work, this is part of my pom, any suggestions.

```
<reporting>
    <outputDirectory>target/site</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8</version>
                        <reports>
                            <report>license</report>
                        </reports>
                    </plugin>
                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: i have tried mvn clean install

Comment: try `mvn site`instead, because you're using the *site* plugin. Afterwards you can look in `target/sites` for your license.

Comment: I have run mvn site and create a lot of html files in target/site but not license

Comment: it does not generate a `target/site/license.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a minimal approach. just add the `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` to your `pom.xml` in the `reporting` section:

```
  ... 
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>target/site</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>license</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  ...
```

the run `mvn clean site` and look at `target/site/license.html`.